# Will my Act 3 mercenary's damage benefit at all from having a weapon?

Tags: diablo-ii

In Diablo 2, giving your mercenary a weapon will vastly increase their effectiveness. Giving my Act II mercenary a 3x socketed pole with Rubies or Topaz for example basically lets them 1-hit everything right up to Duriel.

I've replaced said Pole-wielding mercenary with an Ice Act III mercenary. Reason being that Glacial Spike freezing 3+ enemies is obviously really effective.

This mercenary seems to already do pretty nice damage, but they can still accept a weapon (I think a sword-type weapon and a shield).

I've never seen this particular mercenary ever use a melee attack before (then again, I don't pay much attention).

So, other than having properties that would affect magic damage, resistances or similar obvious benefits; does the weapon help the damage of my mercenary? Maybe it impacts the magic damage even though it would seem odd to do so?

Comment: Give your act 3 merc a spirit weapon (assuming you are on the ladder) to boost their cast rate and they benefit from the + skills too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the mercenary's spells' damage is independent of the sword, and the merc rarely uses the sword (I don't recall *ever* seeing one of them swing his sword, but online sources suggest they do, just rarely, so maybe I just forgot).

It's best to equip them with a weapon that gives other stats, such as resists, faster cast, etc.